# EF Code First Fluent API specifying product, class relationship

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, ef-code-first, fluent

I am trying to create a composite foreign key (if that is the correct term) which enforces a product class type of relationship on a table where the product is mandatory but class is not. I would like to use Code First and the Fluent API to achieve this model.

The scenario is: 
I have commodities which can have many grades and tickets (deliveries) which are required to have a commodity and optionally a grade.

The problem I have is that with the model definition below the commodity/grade relationship is not enforced on tickets. So I can enter a ticket with a grade which is not related to the commodity specified on the ticket.
I have tried various Fluent statements with no success.

How do I create a foreign key which prevents an invalid Commodity Grade from being created in the tickets table?

I have the following model:

```
public class Commodity
{
    public int CommodityId { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; } = new HashSet<Grade>();
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; } = new HashSet<Ticket>();
}

public class Grade
{
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual Commodity Commodity { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; } = new HashSet<Ticket>();
}

public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual Commodity Commodity { get; set; }
    public virtual Grade Grade { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Commodity> Commodities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Commodity>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Grades)
            .WithRequired(c => c.Commodity)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Commodity>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Tickets)
            .WithRequired(t => t.Commodity)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Grade>()
            .HasMany(g => g.Tickets)
            .WithOptional(t => t.Grade);
    }
}
```

Thanks
Tony